# Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely...... because an "if (IsPostback) " infinite loop

Tags: .net, if-statement, stack, infinite-loop

I'm trying to build an project that involves six tables and now I was trying to take an Id from a table and bind it to a drop down list in the form that inserts data to another table (trying to get the Id_copil from copii table while the form is inserting data to Voluntari table)

I've been looking up answers and seems that the problem is in this code :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        drpIngrijire.DataBind();
        drpResponsabil.DataBind();

    }
```

I'm using our teachers' handouts but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: put a break-point somewhere in there and see if it gets hit more often than you expect it to get hit

Comment: Should it be !page.IsPostBack?

Comment: i've put a break there and now it singles like the error being in the "drpIngrijire.DataBind() ; " expression not in the if itself ...